# MS Access 2003 Split database with a table on the FE

Tags: database, ms-access, split

I believe I understand corretly that splitting the DB assumes that all the tables will be on the back end and everything else on the front end.

Here's my problem. I work for a large company and people are all over the country that are using the db. About 60 - 65 people. Usually no more than 4 or 5 synchronously though.

I have one static table that I use as a lookup table on a form that feeds the main table. If I have that static table on the BE, the load time for the form for some people, depending on their distance from the server, can be over two minutes. If I put this static table on the FE, the load time is 4-5 times faster.

My question is; can having the static table cause any other negative issues with my database, or is it just "recommended" that all the tables be on the BE? My thought process is since I get such a huge performance inrease having it on the FE, that if I need to change that static table, I'll just distribute a new FE. Is this sound logic?

Answer (score 1):

Of course yes. If it's just a static lookup table and loading it from the backend each time would take too much time, it's perfectly fine to put it into the frontend.

If you don't want to distribute a new frontend each time the table changes, you could put the table into the backend, and have each frontend import the table on startup:

```
'run this in the frontend on startup
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Your_Table"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC", ";DATABASE=c:\backend.mdb", acTable, "Your_Table", "Your_Table", False
```

(of course you'll have to change the name of your table and the path to the backend appropiately)

Comment: +1 for the suggestion on the import on startup but if it takes over 2 minutes to load the form pulling the data, running the import into the front-end could severely slow down the start up time.

Comment: I almost expected somebody to say something like this. Well, it depends :-) We don't know how exactly the table is used on the main form that takes two minutes to load when the table is in the backend. Maybe importing the whole table over the network goes faster than running some queries on it - who knows. And if the table changes often, maybe he can live with longer startup time if he doesn't have to distribute new frontends that often. It all depends...

Comment: Great, thank you for feedback and I really like the idea of importing the lookup on startup. It's not a big table, but the form that uses it has some code behind it and because it's linked it's slowing it down. Great idea...thank you!

Comment: @Drennen Gaffney: If you like my answer, you can express that by accepting it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your static table can be in the front end. You should also include in the FE, every table that does not change and that is part of a "release", e.g.:  a dashboard menu table.
Anyway, if you have such "roaming" users, I would seriously consider moving the data to a SQL Server, which can really reduce the network trafic, and improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a static table in the FE.  I do that now with tables that are limited strictly to the users and don't need to be saved within the BE database.  Then if you need to add new data just release a new FE to your users.

I think it makes maintenance of the BE easier because then you don't have static/unnecessary tables contained in the BE.  I did that with mine, some static tables went to the FE database and some went into a SQL server database.

It really depends on what you think will be easier for your users as well as for your maintenance.